# Error when iterating - unexpected token

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to iterate to get data-attribute and store it to variable, but I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

```
const monthButton = document.querySelector('.month'),
        annualButton = document.querySelector('.annualy'),
        price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');


monthButton.addEventListener('click', function{
  for(var i=0; i>=4; i++){
    const dataMonth[i] = price[i].dataset.monthly;
  }
})
```

Comment: Missing `()` for the anonymous function.

Comment: Voting to close as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: Also remove const inside your for-loop

Comment: @lumio move a `let dataMonth=[];` outside the loop

Comment: Yes you are right. He needs to define `const dataMonth = [];` outside of for and then just assigning the data inside for as `dataMonth[ i ] = ...`

Comment: But is is not a const. It changes inside the loop

Comment: So: `let dataMonth=[]; monthButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(let i=0; i<=4; i++){
    dataMonth.push(price[i].dataset.monthly);
  }
})`

Answer (score 7):

You didn't specify the parameters for your function: `function{` needs to be changed to `function(e){`.

As well, your for loop will break instantly; change your condition to `i <= 4`.

Also (re)move the `const` since the array should already be defined outside the loop and is not a const

Answer (score 3):

You need smaller or equal to:

```
for(var i=0; i<=4; i++){
```

Read it as *while i is smaller or equal to 4 ...*

Comment: You're right, but it's not related to the error.

Comment: what about declaring `const` in loop

Comment: @ivan, among other issues, that too.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `()` after your anonymus function.

```
monthButton.addEventListener('click', function () { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

you should write the script as following:

```
const monthButton = document.querySelector('.month'),
    annualButton = document.querySelector('.annualy'),
    price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');


monthButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(var i=0; i>=4; i++){
    const dataMonth[i] = price[i].dataset.monthly;
  }
})
```

In order to fix the other issues, this is an updated version:

```
//Used var for each variable instead of const
var monthButton = document.querySelector('.month');
var annualButton = document.querySelector('.annualy');
var price = document.querySelectorAll('.price');

//replaced >= with < as this is logicly the correct one.
// removed the constant definition  as it is not needed.
monthButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(var i=0; **i<4**; i++){
     **dataMonth[i]** = price[i].dataset.monthly;
  }
});
```

Now you still have a problem in your code, what does 4 stands for? and based on what you are assigning the values to the dateMonth, which is not surely an array, If you share the HTML with us, we would fix the issue.

Comment: Add some explanations please

Comment: Two more errors in the code - you need to explain what you changed

Comment: I have only added the "()" after "function", no more, any other errors should be caused by something else.
Anyway, I have just noticed some other issues in your code, I will rewrite everything as I believe should be.